# error: no match for 'operator*'

Tags: qt5, kdiff3

I'm trying to compile KDiff3 in QT5 but I'm stuck on this error, can anyone help?

error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'QAtomicInt' and 'double')

```
m_pProgressBar->setValue( int( 1000.0 * ( i->m_current * (i->m_dRangeMax - i->m_dRangeMin) / i->m_maxNofSteps + i->m_dRangeMin ) ) );
```

The error relates to this section of the above: `m_current *`

Answer (score 0):

operator int() has been removed, try

```
i->m_current.loadAcquire()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this still gives me the same error message, when int() is removed.

Comment: The int() operator has been removed from QAtomicInt. Replace "i->m_current" with "i->m_current.loadAcquire()".

Comment: I've try this but still getting a similar error: 

`m_pProgressBar->setValue( 1000.0 * ( i->m_current.loadAcquire() * (i->m_dRangeMax - i->m_dRangeMin) / i->m_maxNofSteps + i->m_dRangeMin ) );`

**error: no match for 'operator/' (operand types are 'double' and 'QAtomicInt')**